# Sum of rows as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below with (ID, DATE, Category, Price) as columns

[image]

I would like the output as below.

[image]

Could you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: That is a simple aggregate using "sum (case when category in (..) then price else 0) as ..."

Comment: Regular, Bonus, Other is not a column. they are coming from Category column ...

Comment: Nope - you WILL be grouping by date and id. The only mildly complex part is using a case expression for the value to sum.

Comment: this table contain 10 billion rows with 25years data

Comment: if it requires group by ID and Date, will do it

Answer (score 1):

You can go for conditional grouping as given below. you can go for IN clause to make code simpler.

```sql
SELECT ID, DATE, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Category IN ('R','F') THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS Regular,
SUM(CASE WHEN Category IN ('B','C') THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS Bonus,
SUM(CASE WHEN Category IN ('K','W','O','OW') THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS Other 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID, DATE
```

Comment: Thank you, testing it out now

Answer (score -1):

Per my understanding, you want to do group by Date column and show the SUM of the values in new column

Comment: Yes, i want to sum the price  as a column based on the category group

Comment: Please ensure answers are a complete answer to the question, not just a tip which belongs in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (haven't test it):

```
    select ID, Date, 
    sum((case when Category = 'R' then Price) + (case when Category = 'F' then Price)) as 'Regular (R+F)',
    sum((case when Category = 'B' then Price) + (case when Category = 'C' then Price)) as 'Bonus (B+C)',
    sum((case when Category = 'K' then Price) + (case when Category = 'W' then Price) 
        + (case when Category = 'O' then Price) + (case when Category = 'OW' then Price)) as 'Other (K+W+O+OW)'
    from t
    group by Date;
```

Comment: you have couple of syntax error there. `CASE` without `END`. `ID` not in `GROUP BY`